# Windows 7 SHA 256 code signing certificate doesn't save "trust this publisher"

Tags: windows-7, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

We have been using an Authenticode code signing certificate from Globalsign for years to sign our Windows 7 drivers.  Since now there is a move towards new "SHA-256" code signing certificates, we got such a new certificate which works fine under Windows 8.1 or 10, but not under Windows 7.

When I install the driver, Windows ask me if I trust the publisher and offers the checkbox "always trust this publisher", i.e., it offers to save this selection for future installations.  However, under Windows 7 this no longer works, i.e., I get asked every time I install the driver.

I guess this is a bug in Windows 7.  Has anyone else experienced this?  Is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I've experienced exactly the same issue, which is not very convenient when you're trying to install a driver package automatically from the command-line, for instance...

And yes, there is a solution which fixed this for me, you can find a hot-fix on the [Microsoft support website here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2921916).

It is not directly available, but you just have to enter your e-mail address in the form and Microsoft will send it to you.

Comment: I know about this, yet this patch seems not to be distributed via Windows Update, i.e., almost no one has installed it. I am looking for a solution that works on "normal" Windows systems.